# Appium-uiAutomator is working fine for android but not iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am trying to scroll to an element using the following code:

@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator="new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"Contacts\"));")
@iOSFindBy(uiAutomator="new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"Contacts\"));")
public MobileElement orgContact;

This works perfectly in Android but on iOS I get the following error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map: 
- native content: "By.IosUIAutomation: new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Contacts"));"

I have also tried to scroll using:
public void verticalScroll(AppiumDriver driver) {

```
this.driver=driver;
dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
System.out.println("s="+scrollStart);
Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,5000);
```

}
But it also does not work.
Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong here

Answer (score -2):

Shalom Ronit.

The reason that your code doesn't work is because you are using the Android locator strategy also for you `@iOSFindBy` which is wrong, very wrong.

Depending on your Xcode version, you might not be able to use UiAutomator on iOS (in Xcode 8 apple has deleted this option)

You must use ID/Accessibility ID or even Xpath. Please take some time and investigate locator strategies, search for examples and how to correctly find elements for iOS.

I cannot provide much more assistance since I'm not familiar with the app you are trying to  automate. Does this element has ID? is is visible or you must scroll to find it? Do you even know how to use `driver.findBy()?`